# How can I skip empty lines in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot below file using gnuplot with a continues line. the problem is that there is a empty line after each point. I can get a graph with points. Could you please help me?

```
   x y type

   0 -1866.47  i

 100 -1866.52  i

 200 -1867.11  i

 300 -1868.78  i

 400 -1871.58  i

 500 -1875.4   i

 600 -1880.12  i

 700 -1885.62  i

 800 -1891.81  i

 900 -1898.63  i

1000 -1906.02  i

1100 -1913.94  i

1200 -1922.33  i

1300 -1931.17  i

1400 -1940.43  i

1500 -1950.08  i

1600 -1960.11  i

1700 -1970.49  i

1800 -1981.22  i

1900 -1992.27  i

2000 -2003.63  i
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out the file using an external command. E.g, in a *nix OS, you can use `awk`:

```
plot "< awk 'NF!=0 { print $0 }' file.dat" w l
```

(in awk syntax, `NF` gives the number of fields in a given line, and `$0` contains the entire line)

Comment: Hi Joce, this command did not produced any plot in the x11 terminal.

Comment: Does `file.dat` contain the example data above? With your example, you have to skip the first line. But you should get an error message in any case.

Comment: I found it much easier to edit the file first using (grep -e " " file.dat > file1.dat) to remove empty lines and then plot it. problem is that I have several blocks of x,y in the file. gnuplot can not recognise the blocks and produces all lines in the same color.

Comment: That's a possibility, although in some contexts it may not be possible (e.g. if the file is being updated by a background job), so my answer is more general. How are your data blocks marked if you hava line skips everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat with `splot` :D

```
set ticslevel 0
set view 90,0
unset ytics
set xtics offset 0,-1
splot 'empt.txt' u 1:1:2 w l t 'title'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A rather late answer, but already from gnuplot 5.0.0 on (2015), you have the plotting style `with table` (check `help with table`). So, you can do it without external tools (platform-independently) and without `splot`-"cheating".

Simply plot your file (or datablock) in a datablock (or file) which will remove the empty lines.

**Script:**

```
### remove empty lines in data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
   x y type

   0 -1866.47  i

 100 -1866.52  i

 200 -1867.11  i

 300 -1868.78  i

 400 -1871.58  i

 500 -1875.4   i

 600 -1880.12  i

 700 -1885.62  i

 800 -1891.81  i

 900 -1898.63  i

1000 -1906.02  i

1100 -1913.94  i

1200 -1922.33  i

1300 -1931.17  i

1400 -1940.43  i

1500 -1950.08  i

1600 -1960.11  i

1700 -1970.49  i

1800 -1981.22  i

1900 -1992.27  i

2000 -2003.63  i
EOD

set table $NoEmptyLines
    plot $Data u 1:2 w table
unset table

plot $NoEmptyLines u 1:2 w l lc rgb "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Actually, a one-liner without writing to an extra table (and memory) would be with the plotting style `with vectors`. Memorize the previous coordinate and plot a vector from the current coordinate to it. This should work at least for gnuplot>=4.4.0 (2010).

```
plot x1=y1=NaN "Data.dat" u (x0=x1,x1=$1):(y0=y1,y1=$2):(x0-x1):(y0-y1) w vec nohead
```